# undefined local variable or method `user' omniauth callbacks controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, omniauth-facebook

I'm trying to implement facebook login authentication using devise and omniauth, but I got an error during the callback section.

The error goes like this...

```
> `User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."provider" = ? AND "users"."uid" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["provider", "facebook"], ["uid", "1517802078458724"]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 411ms

NameError (undefined local variable or method `user' for #<User:0x007f3008b8a760>):
  app/models/user.rb:34:in `password_required?'
  app/models/user.rb:18:in `block in from_omniauth'
  app/models/user.rb:12:in `tap'
  app/models/user.rb:12:in `from_omniauth'
  app/controllers/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:4:in `all'`
```

It seems like things work until /auth/facebook/ and then it goes up to the part where retrieving uid and provider ends.

My code in controllers, model and routes are as follows..

For callbacks controller and application controller

```
  class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  def all
    user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    if user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect user, notice: "Signed in!"
    else
      session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
  alias_method :facebook, :all
end


class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

end
```

My user.rb model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authentications
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :omniauthable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
      user.save!
    end
  end

  def self.new_with_sessions(params, session)
    if session["devise.user_attributes"]
      new(session["devise.user_attributes"], without_protection: true ) do |user|
        user.attributes = params
        user.valid?
      end
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def password_required?
    super && user.blank?

  end
end
```

My schema.rb

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20141120211712) do

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "oauth_token"
    t.datetime "oauth_expires_at"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

My routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "omniauth_callbacks" } 
  root            'static_pages#home'
  get 'help' =>   'static_pages#help'
  get 'about' =>  'static_pages#about'
  get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
```

and finally my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby   '2.1.4'

gem 'rails',                   '4.2.0.beta4'
gem 'bcrypt',                  '3.1.7'
gem 'faker',                   '1.4.2'
gem 'carrierwave',             '0.10.0'
gem 'mini_magick',             '3.8.0'
gem 'fog',                     '1.23.0'
gem 'will_paginate',           '3.0.7'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',          '3.2.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails',              '5.0.0.beta1'
gem 'uglifier',                '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails',            '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails',            '4.0.0.beta2'
gem 'turbolinks',              '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',                '2.2.3'
gem 'rails-html-sanitizer',    '1.0.1'
gem 'sdoc',                    '0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'devise', github: 'plataformatec/devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-linkedin'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'protected_attributes'
```

I would really like this feature of facebook login in my app... Thank you very much in advance. I would greatly appreciate any input..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `password_required?` which is called when the user is saved.

```
def password_required?
  super && user.blank?

end
```

Its trying to test whether the `user` is blank? However the user variable/method does not exist in its scope. Instead you need to use `self` which refers to the current instance of User.

So the line should be:

```
super && self.blank?
```

or just:

```
super && blank?
```

Comment: Now I get ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Email can't be blank): error. what shall I do now?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem throughmaking

```
def password_required?
  super && user.blank?

end
```

into

```
super && self.blank?
```

and I also added

```
user.email = auth.info.email
```

to the `self.from_omniauth(auth)` section.
Thanks guys